# Sphere - Locus of points at a constant great circle distance from another point

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, spheres

Consider a sphere $\mathcal{S}$ of radius $R$, and $O\left(R,\theta_0,\phi_0\right)$ a point on this sphere.

I am trying to characterize the locus of points at a constant great circle distance from $O$.
That is, given $0<r<R$ , is it possible to find a simple condition on $(\theta,\phi)$ so that $d\left(O~;~M(R,\theta,\phi)\right)=r$, where $d$ is the great circle distance.

Using the expression of this distance, this yields the following :
$\cos(\theta)\cos(\theta_0)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta_0)\cos(\phi-\phi_0) = \cos(r/R)$.
Is there a way to obtain a simpler relation? Ideally I would like to have an analytical solution, but something that could be easily solved numerically would interest me as well.

Comment: In the past I've solved this by "rotating" the point $O$ to (say) the north pole, where it is evident the locus of points you ask about is a "line" of constant latitude, then rotating the north pole back to $O$.  How many details need to be carried through depends on your application.

Comment: It would improve the question to define $\theta,\phi$ as longitude and latitude (as you defined the radius $R$).

Comment: The locus of points is a circle with radius $r'$, centered at signed distance $d'$ from the center of the sphere towards $O$, as @hardmath commented. (If $r \le R$, then $d' \ge 0$; if $r = R$, then $d' = 0$, $r' = R$; if $r \ge R$, then $d' \lt 0$ and $r' \le R$.) Both $r'$ and $d'$ are trivial to compute in Cartesian coordinates, in my opinion. If this helps, I'd be happy to work out their expressions as an answer, although I do believe you would have done it yourself already, if it was applicable to your underlying problem.